# Declaring global variable in module/ Looping in mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, programming, scoping

I'm new and still learning about mathematica. I'm having some trouble with my code. This is my current code that i'm having trouble with:

```
q2 = 0.05;
k = 155900;

{rr2 = 2 k q1^2 q2 + 2 k q1 q2^2, 
  rr3 = q1^2 + 2 q1 q2 + (k^2 + 1) q2^2};
ee2 = k q1 q2;
ee3 = b2 /. Solve[2 b2 - σ^2 == 2 k* q2, {b2}]
oo5 = (-b1^2 + 2 (ee2) (ee3) == rr2);
{ee4, ee5} = b1 /. Solve[oo5, {b1}];
oo6 = (2 (ee2) + (ee3)^2 - 2 (ee5) σ == rr3);
oo8 = σ /. Solve[oo6, {σ}];
oo9 = Extract[oo8, {8}];

calcJ[q1_] := 
 Module[{bd, X1, inverseX1, X2, value1, value2, b0, b1, b2, σ, 
   X}, bd = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {-q2, k q2}, {q1, 0}};
  X1 = {{-b0 q1 q2 σ, b0 q1 q2 - b1 q1 q2 σ, 
     b1 q1 q2 - b2 q1 q2 σ, 
     b2 q1 q2 - k  q1 q2^2 - 
      q1 q2 σ^2}, {b0 q1^2 σ, -b0 q1^2 + k^2 q1^2 q2^2 +
       b1 q1^2 σ, -b1 q1^2 + b2 q1^2 σ, -b2 q1^2 + 
      2 k q1^2 q2 + q1^2 σ^2}, {-b0 b2 q1 q2 + k  b0 q1 q2^2 + 
      b0 q1 q2 σ^2, -b1 b2 q1 q2 + k  b1 q1 q2^2 - 
      b0 q1 q2 σ + b1 q1 q2 σ^2, 
     b0 q1 q2 - b2^2 q1 q2 + k  b2 q1 q2^2 - b1 q1 q2 σ + 
      b2 q1 q2 σ^2, 
     b1 q1 q2 - 2 b2 q1 q2 σ + k  q1 q2^2 σ + 
      q1 q2 σ^3}, {b0 b2 q1^2 - 2 k b0 q1^2 q2 - 
      b0 q1^2 σ^2, 
     b1 b2 q1^2 - 2 k b1 q1^2 q2 + b0 q1^2 σ - 
      b1 q1^2 σ^2, -b0 q1^2 + b2^2 q1^2 - 2 k b2 q1^2 q2 + 
      k^2 q1^2 q2^2 + b1 q1^2 σ - 
      b2 q1^2 σ^2, -b1 q1^2 + 2 b2 q1^2 σ - 
      2 k q1^2 q2 σ - q1^2 σ^3}};
  inverseX1 = Inverse[X1];
  X2 = {{-b0 q1^2 - b0 q1 q2, -b1 q1^2 - b1 q1 q2, -b2 q1^2 - 
      b2 q1 q2 + k  q1^2 q2, -q1^2 σ - 
      q1 q2 σ}, {b0 q1^2 + b0 q1 q2 - k^2 q1^2 q2^2, 
     b1 q1^2 + b1 q1 q2, 
     b2 q1^2 + b2 q1 q2 - 2 k q1^2 q2 - k  q1 q2^2, 
     q1^2 σ + q1 q2 σ}, {0, -k  q1^2 q2, 
     0, -q1^2 - q1 q2}, {-b0 b1 + 2 b0 b2 σ - 
      2 k b0 q2 σ - b0 σ^3, -b1^2 - b0 b2 + 2 k b0 q2 - 
      k  q1 q2^2 + 2 b1 b2 σ - 2 k b1 q2 σ + 
      b0 σ^2 - b1 σ^3, -2 b1 b2 + 2 k b1 q2 - 
      b0 σ + 2 b2^2 σ - 2 k b2 q2 σ + 
      b1 σ^2 - b2 σ^3, 
     b0 - b2^2 + 2 k b2 q2 - q1 q2 - (k^2 + 1) q2^2 - 2 b1 σ + 
      3 b2 σ^2 - 2 k q2 σ^2 - σ^4}};
  value1 = {b0 -> 155900 q1 q2, 
    b1 -> 10 Sqrt[1559]
       Sqrt[-2 q1^2 q2 + 311798 q1 q2^2 + q1 q2 σ^2], 
    b2 -> 1/2 (311800 q2 + σ^2)};
  value2 = {σ -> 
     Sqrt[2] √(-10 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[q1] Sqrt[q2] - 
         155900 q2 + √(q1^2 + 20 Sqrt[3118] q1^(3/2) Sqrt[q2] + 
            623602 q1 q2 + 3118020 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[q1] q2^(3/2) + 
            24304810001 q2^2))};
  X = X2.inverseX1;
  (-Transpose[bd].X) /. value1 /. value2]

i = Input["Number of examples?"];
v = RandomInteger[200, i]
q1 = 1/v;

calcJ /@ q1

(*{164, 101}*)
(*{{{0.00124695, -1.00002, 0.0113292, -18.111}, {-0.499998, 
   0.998766, -1765.81, -0.0113703}}, {{0.00159016, -1., 
   0.0113323, -14.2124}, {-0.500005, 0.998399, -1765.76, -0.0113536}}}*)
```

This module works fine and gives the answer that I'm looking for. What im trying to do now is to change `value1` and `value2` inside the `Module` from before into this:

```
value1 = {b0 -> ee2, b1 -> ee5, b2 -> ee3};
value2 = {σ -> oo9};
```

If I typed it in manually as shown in my default code, then the module works fine but not when I tried to change it to above. I need to change the `value1` and `value2` as above because the variable is used on other part of my code. Can someone point me to the right direction on solving this problem?

**EDIT 1:**

After following @m_goldberg suggestion, I'm still stuck with errors. Your guidance is greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
{rr2 = 2 k q1^2 q2 + 2 k q1 q2^2, 
  rr3 = q1^2 + 2 q1 q2 + (k^2 + 1) q2^2};
ee2 = k q1 q2;
ee3 = b2 /. Solve[2 b2 - σ^2 == 2 k* q2, {b2}];
oo5 = (-b1^2 + 2 (ee2) (ee3) == rr2);
{ee4, ee5} = b1 /. Solve[oo5, {b1}];
oo6 = (2 (ee2) + (ee3)^2 - 2 (ee5) σ == rr3);
oo8 = σ /. Solve[oo6, {σ}];
oo9 = Extract[oo8, {8}];
q2 = 0.05;
k = 155900;
calcJ[q1_, σ_, b0_, b1_, b2_] := 
 Module[{bd, X1, inverseX1, X2, X}, 
  bd = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {-q2, k q2}, {q1, 0}};
  X1 = {{-b0 q1 q2 σ, b0 q1 q2 - b1 q1 q2 σ, 
     b1 q1 q2 - b2 q1 q2 σ, 
     b2 q1 q2 - k  q1 q2^2 - 
      q1 q2 σ^2}, {b0 q1^2 σ, -b0 q1^2 + k^2 q1^2 q2^2 +
       b1 q1^2 σ, -b1 q1^2 + b2 q1^2 σ, -b2 q1^2 + 
      2 k q1^2 q2 + q1^2 σ^2}, {-b0 b2 q1 q2 + k  b0 q1 q2^2 + 
      b0 q1 q2 σ^2, -b1 b2 q1 q2 + k  b1 q1 q2^2 - 
      b0 q1 q2 σ + b1 q1 q2 σ^2, 
     b0 q1 q2 - b2^2 q1 q2 + k  b2 q1 q2^2 - b1 q1 q2 σ + 
      b2 q1 q2 σ^2, 
     b1 q1 q2 - 2 b2 q1 q2 σ + k  q1 q2^2 σ + 
      q1 q2 σ^3}, {b0 b2 q1^2 - 2 k b0 q1^2 q2 - 
      b0 q1^2 σ^2, 
     b1 b2 q1^2 - 2 k b1 q1^2 q2 + b0 q1^2 σ - 
      b1 q1^2 σ^2, -b0 q1^2 + b2^2 q1^2 - 2 k b2 q1^2 q2 + 
      k^2 q1^2 q2^2 + b1 q1^2 σ - 
      b2 q1^2 σ^2, -b1 q1^2 + 2 b2 q1^2 σ - 
      2 k q1^2 q2 σ - q1^2 σ^3}};
  inverseX1 = Inverse[X1];
  X2 = {{-b0 q1^2 - b0 q1 q2, -b1 q1^2 - b1 q1 q2, -b2 q1^2 - 
      b2 q1 q2 + k  q1^2 q2, -q1^2 σ - 
      q1 q2 σ}, {b0 q1^2 + b0 q1 q2 - k^2 q1^2 q2^2, 
     b1 q1^2 + b1 q1 q2, 
     b2 q1^2 + b2 q1 q2 - 2 k q1^2 q2 - k  q1 q2^2, 
     q1^2 σ + q1 q2 σ}, {0, -k  q1^2 q2, 
     0, -q1^2 - q1 q2}, {-b0 b1 + 2 b0 b2 σ - 
      2 k b0 q2 σ - b0 σ^3, -b1^2 - b0 b2 + 2 k b0 q2 - 
      k  q1 q2^2 + 2 b1 b2 σ - 2 k b1 q2 σ + 
      b0 σ^2 - b1 σ^3, -2 b1 b2 + 2 k b1 q2 - 
      b0 σ + 2 b2^2 σ - 2 k b2 q2 σ + 
      b1 σ^2 - b2 σ^3, 
     b0 - b2^2 + 2 k b2 q2 - q1 q2 - (k^2 + 1) q2^2 - 2 b1 σ + 
      3 b2 σ^2 - 2 k q2 σ^2 - σ^4}};

  X = X2.inverseX1;
  (-Transpose[bd].X)]

i = Input["Number of examples?"];
v = RandomInteger[200, i]
q1 = 1/v;

calcJ[#, oo9, ee2, ee5, ee3] & /@ q1
```

**EDIT 2:**

After following @bills suggestion, the code seems to work partly. I would get the answer when `i=1`(number of examples). But when its more than 1, the answers seems to be jumbled up. Besides that, when I tried to change `q1=1/204.8` I cant get the answer needed. Lets say that i have a set of `v={204.8,69.2,34.4,...}`, how do I debug/rewrite the code for it to works? Below is the latest code:

```
k=155900;
{rr2=2k q12 q2+2k q1 q22,rr3=q12+2 q1 q2+(k^2+1) q22};
ee2=k q1 q2;
ee3=b2/.Solve[2 b2-σ2==2k* q2,{b2}];
oo5=(-b1^2+2 (ee2)(ee3)==rr2);
{ee4,ee5}=b1/.Solve[oo5,{b1}];
oo6=(2 (ee2)+(ee3)^2-2 (ee5) σ==rr3);
oo8=σ/.Solve[oo6,{σ}];
oo9=Extract[oo8,{8}];


q2=0.05;
value1={b0->ee2,b1->ee5,b2->ee3};
value2={σ->oo9};
calcJ[q1_]:=Module[{bd,X1,inverseX1,X2,X},bd={{0,0},{0,0},{-q2,k q2},{q1,0}};
  X1={{-b0 q1 q2 σ,b0 q1 q2-b1 q1 q2 σ,b1 q1 q2-b2 q1 q2 σ,
b2 q1 q2-k  q1 q2^2-q1 q2 σ^2},
{b0 q1^2 σ,-b0 q1^2+k^2 q1^2 q2^2+b1 q1^2 σ,
-b1 q1^2+b2 q1^2 σ,-b2 q1^2+2k q1^2 q2+q1^2 σ^2},
{-b0 b2 q1 q2+k  b0 q1 q2^2+b0 q1 q2 σ^2,
-b1 b2 q1 q2+k  b1 q1 q2^2-b0 q1 q2 σ+b1 q1 q2 σ^2,
b0 q1 q2-b2^2 q1 q2+k  b2 q1 q2^2-b1 q1 q2 σ+b2 q1 q2 σ^2
,b1 q1 q2-2 b2 q1 q2 σ+k  q1 q2^2 σ+q1 q2 σ^3},
{b0 b2 q1^2-2k b0 q1^2 q2-b0 q1^2 σ^2,b1 b2 q1^2-2k b1 q1^2 q2+b0 q1^2 σ-b1 q1^2 σ^2,
-b0 q1^2+b2^2 q1^2-2k b2 q1^2 q2+k^2 q1^2 q2^2+b1 q1^2 σ-b2 q1^2 σ^2,
-b1 q1^2+2 b2 q1^2 σ-2k q1^2 q2 σ-q1^2 σ^3}};
  inverseX1=Inverse[X1];
  X2={{-b0 q1^2-b0 q1 q2,-b1 q1^2-b1 q1 q2,-b2 q1^2-b2 q1 q2+k  q1^2 q2,-q1^2 σ-q1 q2 σ},
{b0 q1^2+b0 q1 q2-k^2 q1^2 q2^2,
b1 q1^2+b1 q1 q2,b2 q1^2+b2 q1 q2-2k q1^2 q2-k  q1 q2^2,q1^2 σ+q1 q2 σ},
{0,-k  q1^2 q2,0,-q1^2-q1 q2},
{-b0 b1+2 b0 b2 σ-2k b0 q2 σ-b0 σ^3,
-b1^2-b0 b2+2k b0 q2-k  q1 q2^2+2 b1 b2 σ-2k b1 q2 σ+b0 σ^2-b1 σ^3,
-2 b1 b2+2k b1 q2-b0 σ+2 b2^2 σ-2k b2 q2 σ+b1 σ^2-b2 σ^3,
b0-b2^2+2k b2 q2-q1 q2-(k^2+1) q2^2-2 b1 σ+3 b2 σ^2-2k q2 σ^2-σ^4}};


  X=X2.inverseX1;
  (-Transpose[bd].X)/.value1/.value2]

i=Input["Number of examples?"];
v=RandomInteger[200,i];
q1=1/v;

calcJ/@q1
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: I don't see completely what you are trying to do, but if you want to change the value of the variables value1 and value2 from inside the module, then do not specify them as local variables, i.e.,remove them from the brackets in the first argument of Module. Then they will be global.

Comment: @bills Thank you for the suggestion. It seems that the code almost works after following your suggestion. But a few problem arises after that. I have updated the code above and your kind help on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to debug your code -- it is too big a mess -- but here is a suggestion on how to proceed.

I suggest you pass the parameters you are trying to inject into your module as additional arguments to `calcJ`. With this approach, you code would take the general form

```
calcJ[q1_, σ_, b0_, b1_, b2_] :=  Module[{bd, X1, inverseX1, X2, X},  ...]
```

and you would use like so

```
calcJ[#, oo9, ee2, ee5, ee3] & /@ q1
```

With this approach you no longer need the local variables `value1, value2, b0, b1, b2, σ` and you can simplify your code and things should go more smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry about the mess of my code. I've tried tackling the problem using your suggestion. But can't seem to get the answer. I'm stuck at this problem for almost 2 weeks now. Your help and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AhmadRuzaini禅. If you edit your question to show the latest version of your code, we can try to help you further.